# Create custom ROM in Android

Tags: android

I am beginner level Android developer and I want to make a stock Rom to customized ROM via coding and not by manually. Is there any possibility to do this. Someone please guide me to correct path.

Comment: Hi ,just see this link. this link contain complete            procedure for making of custom rom in android.afterwards i found this.use it guys.                                                  http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2195858

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1801690

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I want to make a stock Rom to customized ROM via coding and not by
>   manually. Is there any possibility to do this.

go through the following link, it will provide good demonstration for how to setup Custom ROM's,

[Create Your Own Custom ROM for Android](http://theunlockr.com/2010/03/26/how-to-create-your-own-custom-rom-for-android-part-1-setting-up-the-kitchen/)

Also have a look at [Getting started with creating custom ROMs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6232620/1626878), it contains some usefull links for how to do it.

Comment: use this link :http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2195858

Comment: The first is about android kitchen which is old a little bit today.

Comment: Amazing guide from xda devs: https://forum.xda-developers.com/chef-central/android/guide-android-rom-development-t2814763