# Which target AOSP to build for a Galaxy A12?

Tags: android, android-source

I have a Galaxy A12 phone and want to build AOSP and flash it to my device. I figured I should be working with Android 12 as that is what is currently installed on my device according to `Settings->About Phone->Software Information`. So I downloaded `android-12.1.0_r26` like so:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-12.1.0_r26
repo sync -c -j8
```

The problem is the vast array of choices I get when I run `lunch`. According to a Google search I concluded that my phone's processor is a `ARM` 64 bit. So I was thinking something like `2. aosp_arm64-eng` or `71. sdk_car_arm64-userdebug`. Am I on the right track here?

Also for bonus points am I right in thinking that if I get this wrong I am in danger of making my phone unusable and unrecoverable?

Comment: Related: [What is the meaning of AOSP's 'lunch' combinations and what do I need to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31028167/295004) and [Create custom ROM in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14601176/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks for the links. Have you ever done this successfully? Am I about to break my phone?

Comment: Bricking your phone is always a possibility, see [Why are there not generic phone OS installers?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/63630/3573) and [Why Android devices are more brickable than PCs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205072/3573) I would look for an existing Custom ROM for your device from a site like XDA forums. My experience is with older Google Nexus devices where Google provides the [Factory Image and drivers](https://developers.google.com/android/images) but would only work on those specific devices/versions of device.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I just contacted Samsung via their live chat. Apparently they don't use ASOP. They have their own in house code base. I am in discussions with them about how to download their code base. On the live chat they said that there should be an option under ```Settings -> Software update``` but there is no such setting there. They told me to send feedback on their Samsung Members app. I've done that and am awaiting a response.